# How can I help my dog that is afraid of other dogs?

Tags: dogs, behavior, fear

I have a dog that has 3 months and 3 weeks and I walk with her regularly along the street since she was 2 and a half months, I also have an old dog (15 years) that's blind and they live together.

But my younger dog is afraid of any kind, size and age dog we see on the walks we do.  She hides behind me, cries, and hide her tail between legs, and when the other dogs tries to smell her or anything she growls. She has met younger dogs, male, female, older but never a rough dog, so I don't know why she's always afraid.

What can I do to help her get over her fear?

Comment: It is natural for puppies to be afraid of other dogs. Just ignore it and let it understand that other dogs are friendly and reacts to signals.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Socialization is really important for dogs in the first 3 months. The aspca has a great article about socialization [here](http://www.aspca.org/pet-care/virtual-pet-behaviorist/dog-behavior/socializing-your-puppy)

When socializing, take it slow, be relaxed(this is important, your dog can sense if you are anxious which only makes the situation worse) and praise praise praise after a successful encounter.

If you have friends with dogs or meet someone willing to help you - it's worth it to work with a dog that you are familiar with(yours would probably be perfect). Have your pup sit on a leash while the other person is out of sight. Have treats (hot dogs or chicken, something with a stronger scent to keep attention). Have the other person walk by with the dog, and before your pup even notices the other dog get her attention with a treat and keep her attention as the other dog walks by. This helps her get used to other dogs being in the vicinity before moving up to direct socialization.

If you really can't get her used to direct contact with other dogs, you might want to invest in a class that will help your pup learn how to socialize properly.